# How long will Brown Dwarfs live?

Tags: astrophysics, time, stars, brown-dwarfs

Brown Dwarfs are a technical *star* because of their masses. If Red Dwarfs live for 10 trillion years, then how long could Brown Dwarfs live?

Comment: Brown dwarves are technically NOT a star, precisely because of their mass. Otherwise a nail is technically a screw, too, because it fixes on thing to another

Answer (score 2):

Brown dwarfs are *not* stars, because apart from a brief period of deuterium fusion in their early lives, their overall composition will remain unaltered by nuclear reactions.

There is no certain time limit to a brown dwarf's existence$^\dagger$. They will simply sit and cool; they will become more dense and their interiors will become more and more electron-degenerate. Ultimately, they will asymptotically approach resembling a cold white dwarf made mostly of hydrogen and helium and almost entirely supported by electron degeneracy pressure.

$^\dagger$ Unless [protons decay](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proton_decay).